# Does seqhilo generator work with NHibernate batching?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm aware that generators that require round trips to the database (identity in particular) don't work with batching, but does seqhilo work with batching?  I'm unclear on this as it does require one roundtrip to acquire the high value, but after that it has X low values to work with on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.

The generators that don't work with batching are those that require *inserting the actual record* in order to retrieve the Id value, like `identity`.

`seqhilo` is just a `hilo` implementation which uses real sequences instead of a sequence-like table.